# Graph a quadratic function using transformations

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, quadratics

I was wondering if you could suggest me some good textbook or materials for "Graph a quadratic function using transformations". I am looking for beautiful/fun materials on Graph a quadratic function using transformations for non-math people. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See this resource on Khan Academy: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/quadratics/transforming-quadratic-functions/v/shifting-and-scaling-parabolas.

Or visit this Desmos Graph I've created: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vdewabwzai.